# How can I resolve 404 and Not Authorized errors when requesting a bearer token for EUIPO API connection?

Tags: rest

I've been trying to connect to the EUIPO API but nothing seems to work. Anyone here has been able to make a simple request to the API? I'm trying to get a simple search result for the trademark database. I would appreciate any kind of help.

I have managed to create an app access and get an api key and a secret but it seems you need to create a first request to get a bearer token (necessary for everything else) but I keep getting a 404 on the request or a not authorized. The guide I'm using can be found here:

https://dev.euipo.europa.eu/faq

import requests
import json

```
url = "https://auth.euipo.europa.eu/oidc/accessToken"

payload = {
    'client_id': 'my api key',
    'client_secret': 'my secret',
    'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
}

headers = {
     'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

# print the status code and raw response
print("Status Code:", response.status_code)
print("Response Text:", response.text)
```

the code above returns a 404 on the url and if I change to sandbox says I'm not authorized.
if anyone has more info on this I would appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the scope in your payload:

```
def get_access_token():
url = f"https://{auth_endpoint}/oidc/accessToken"
payload = {
    "client_id": CLIENT_ID,
    "client_secret": CLIENT_SECRET,
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "scope": "uid"
}
headers = {
    'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'User-Agent': "Insomnia/2023.5.5"
}
print(f"url: {url}\n\n")

response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
if response.status_code == 200 and 'application/json' in response.headers.get('content-type', ''):
    data = response.json()
    print(f"data: {data}\n\n")
    return data.get("access_token", None)
else:
    print(f"Error {response.status_code}: {response.text}")
    return None
```